# Запятая в сложном союзе в начале предложения

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли здесь расставлены запятые?

"Для того, чтобы создать новый документ, следует воспользоваться пунктом меню".

Мне кажется запятых здесь вообще не должно быть.

Answer (score 4):

Для того чтобы создать новый документ, следует воспользоваться пунктом меню.

Сложноподчиненное предложение с придаточным цели, союз ДЛЯ ТОГО ЧТОБЫ **в начале предложения обычно не расчленяется,** тем более что стиль деловой.

Comment: Спасибо, но я не знаю, как удалить.